# Prime coordinates in electrostatics/electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

If I know that my formula for potential is:

$ V(r) = - \int \vec{E}(\vec r\prime)\cdot d\vec l\prime$.

I am taking this us for potential; this can be worth for charge density; current density etc...

I just want to make sure that I have properly distinguished difference between primed and unprimed coordinates.

Prime coordinates should always be the one that are source (e.g. source of charge - source of current) of my whatever I am looking to find and unprimed coordinates are the ones where I am looking what I want to observe?

Comment: So usually the primed coordinates do mean that, but I think you are not using them correctly in the integral itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would normally write this as:

$$ V(r) = -\int_\infty^r E(r')dr' $$

so you are using the $r'$ variable inside the the integral and the unprimed $r$ is a limit of the integral. To take a concrete example, take a charge $Q$ so the force (per unit charge) is:

$$ F(r') = \frac{kQ}{r'^2} $$

Then:

$$ V(r) = -\int_\infty^r \frac{kQ}{r'^2} dr' $$

And if we do the integral we get:

$$ V(r) = -\left[ -\frac{kQ}{r'} \right]_\infty^r $$

Then putting in the limits $\infty$ and $r$ gives us:

$$\begin{align}
 V(r) &= \frac{kQ}{r} - \frac{kQ}{\infty} \\
      &= \frac{kQ}{r}
\end{align}$$